# What could this PLA be doing?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, computer-architecture, hardware

The picture below shows a PLA, I have done part (a) and found out that;
$$
F_0 = A_0 \mathbin{\oplus} B_0 \\
F_1 = A_0B_0 + (\overline{A_0} + \overline{B_0})(A_1  \mathbin{\oplus} B_1) \\
F_2 = A_0B_0(A_1 + B_1) + A_1B_1\\
$$

What may this circuit be doing, I can't see a function for it?

[image]

I have got the output fro  a program, i would want another opinion of what it may be doing, so that I can edit my guess;

[image]

-------------------------------------------------------------> EDIT

I don't get it, may be am not good at realizing patterns, I have interchanged both 1st and 3rd output and don't see a thing

[image]

Comment: Create a table of all 16 possible inputs and their output values and the answer will likely be obvious to you.

Comment: i got the output but still confused on what it could be doing

Comment: Swap the order of your 1st and 3rd output columns (and maybe put a space between your A vs B input ones) and you might see it.

Comment: i just don't see anything, its not adding because some are not the same Am lost

Comment: OH thanks guys, I realized it. This is adding A+B = F

Comment: Congrats.  Now that you have your answer, post it in the answer form so the question shows as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit is an adder with \$F[2:0]=A[1:0]+B[1:0]\$.

Comment: Despite the comment of @ChrisStratton, the OP has not posted the answer in the comments as an actual answer.  I've posted in as an actual answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.